# Callback function on change event

Tags: ajax, javascript

I need to execute some functions when a field value changes. I tried both Drupal AJAX framework and classical Jquery, but in both cases the callback function is not executed.  Adding a Jquery .change() :

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#foo").change( function(){
      var selected_date = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MYURL/"+selected_date ,
        data: selected_date,
        success: alert( selected_date)
      });
    });
  })
})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

The Jquery works fine. Then

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_menu().
*/
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['MYURL/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_get_liberte_id', 
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  return $items;
}

function MYMODULE_get_liberte_id ($selected_date) {
  //DB queries and form alter or error messages here
}
```

I also tried with AJAX Framework :

```
//hook form alter
$form['foo']['#ajax'] = array(
  'callback' => 'MYMODULE_ajax_callback',
  'wrapper' => '.center-wrapper',
 );

function MYMODULE_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
  //is the function fired ???
  $commands[] = ajax_command_alert(t('MYMODULE_ajax_callback fired'));
  return '<div id="wrapper">'.date('Y-m-d').'<xmp>'.print_r($form_state['values'], true).'</xmp></div>';
  //DB queries and form alter or error messages here
}
```

`dsm($form)` shows that the field got #ajax attribute, but the callback function isn't executed.

I'm afraid I'm not on the right way, or at list I'm missing something :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#ajax['wrapper']` value should be id attribute, not a class, and without '#'. You can look about this [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax_wrapper). The callback function should return a html content, a renderable array (which will replace the 'wrapper' on a call) or array of [drupal ajax commands](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7). You can try this and your code should work:

```
function MYMODULE_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
   $commands[] = ajax_command_alert(t('MYMODULE_ajax_callback fired'));
   return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Indeed I forgot to return sthing !!! But return $commands didn't work, I had to use return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);   Anyway I'm still fighting a step forward... How can I return updates for $form AND $form_state at the same time, and for various fields of the form ?

Comment: Ah yes, I updated the answer. You don't need return $form_state or $form. In your hook_form_alter $form_state should be already updated with it's values (for this I think you need to take $form_state by reference in ajax callback function). So you can change the form depending on form state values and also add to $commands array something like this: $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#selector', drupal_render($form['something']));

Comment: well, I'm afraid I don't understand the exact possibilities of the callback fn... I tried to change form_state['values'] by reference but nope. I think I'll have to post another question... As you inserted my comment in the answer I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks a lot